# Parsing NON-XML syntax'ed TEXT file in C#

Tags: c#

How does one write a custom parser in C# to parse a TEXT file that is formatted by custom tags? ***WITHOUT using XML / 3rd Party Libs***

```
[product] 
*name*Name1*/name*
*cost*100*/cost*
[/product]
[product]
*name*Name2*/name*
*cost*120*/cost*
[/product]
...
```

I'm trying to parse it in a way that I can store "Name1" and "Name2" in strings, etc.

Comment: I really don't see the point of creating your own parser. Just use XML or even JSON! Why do you want to invent a whole new format in the first place? Is this some kind of assignment or something?

Comment: Yes this is some kind of assignment. Some help would be great instead of asking me to use XML or JSON again. If I could have, I would already have.

Comment: @Shaharyar What? I have a / in the 2nd and 4th `product` which closes off each product group if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky way to do it.

Let me just give you some general guidelines on this *very* hacky solution.

I see that your format is very similar to XML. So you can just loop through the string and keep a boolean variable `flag`, initialised with `true`.

```
For each character in the string, 
    if it is a `[`, replace it with `<`. 
    If it is a `]`, replace it with `>`. 
    If it is a `*`, check the flag. 
        If the flag is true, replace it with `<`. 
        If the flag is false, replace it with a `>`. 
        Then, flag = !flag;
```

Now you have an xml representation. And you can parse it with the XML parser that is built into the .NET Framework. No third party libraries used! The input text is still in the original format, not changed to XML!

REQUIREMENT MET!

Comment: This works. Only issue is that, lets just say, my I'm tasked to write a custom parser and part of the requirement was to ditch XML / JSON completely. Thanks for the answer regardless though.

Comment: @SamuelNg Maybe you can try to learn regular expressions. Those help a _lot_ in writing these parsers!

Comment: I have been looking into regex earlier, does seem like something that may solve my issue. Thanks!